# How to display datepicker in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am new for android. I created sample application. I picked `DatePicker` from the android studio palette. If I click it, it's not working. How it works? Where should I write function? I'm using android studio not eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**Date Pickers let you pick a date that is correctly formatted and adjusted to the user’s locale.**

```
public abstract void onDateChanged (DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

Called upon a date change.

Example :

```
 public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, 
       int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      info.setText(
        "Year: " + year + "\n" +
        "Month of Year: " + monthOfYear + "\n" +
        "Day of Month: " + dayOfMonth);

     }});
```

Reference [1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html),[2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/example-of-using-datepicker-and.html)

Comment: dear @appu kindly read the post as it is clearly described and also go through the reference ..and after all if was helpful do mark answer

Answer (score 0):

In your activity onCreate() method you can initialize the `DatePicker` like this

```
   datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);

        Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();

        datePicker.init(
                ca.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                ca.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                new OnDateChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view,
                                              int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       //Do what you want

                    }
                });
```

Comment: throw error in this variable curr_year,curr_month,curr_day